# Thread Local Storage in Grand Central Dispatch

Tags: pthreads, grand-central-dispatch

Is it possible to use TLS in GCD? I'd like to dispatch tasks that need to access hardware driver queues. I need to associate a queue with each thread so that they can be both load balanced and accessed concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of TLS in GCD is dispatch_queue_set_specific/dispatch_get_specific. Associating a queue with a particular thread isn't something you can do though.